# IE11 hangs when emptying large <select> list due to seperate textarea on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, textarea, internet-explorer-11

I've been looking into an issue when trying to empty a div that contains a  control with a large number or options (~30000).  I know, it's ridiculous, but nothing I can do about the number.  I've narrowed it down to somehow being related to also entering information into a textarea control on the same page.

This issue seems to have just manifested with a recent update to IE11.  Previous Update Version 11.0.20 didn't do this, but 11.0.25 does, not sure if it's that specific update or somewhere in between.

Please see the following for a stripped down example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jelston/epmpb2j4/4/

If you click Create, then Populate, then Empty you should see that it happens fairly quickly.  However if you click Create, Populate, then enter any text in the textarea, then click Empty it will hang for a while.  What I'm seeing is usually 15 seconds or so but I'm sure that could vary based on PC.  At this point it will hang every time even if you clear out the text until you refresh the page.

If you look at the javascript you'll see it's not even within the div that is being emptied and there is nothing trying to access the textarea in any way.

I'm thinking this is just an IE bug at this point, but don't want to throw out poorly formed HTML or javascript, I just can't see anything wrong.  I've tried a few different methods for clearing it but all seem to behave the same:

```
.html("")
.detach().remove()
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "";
```

Thanks a lot to anyone who takes the time to look at this and has any suggestions.  This is my first question I've posted on SO, so let me know if I could be doing something better.

Comment: Not for nuthin' but you're seriously taxing any browser with a 3000 selection of any kind of object.  It's a miracle it works on anything at all.  I submit that the solution to your problem is to change that thing to some other idea.

Comment: I second durbnpoisn... and like you said yourself, that's just ridiculous! And did you mean "30,000" or "3000". The latter is bonkers, the former is down right insanity. What are the options and what is it's purpose?

Comment: It's around 30,000.  The application is used internally to index documents to IBM Content Manager and the <select> is pulled from a data source and used to ensure consistency in the entered information for this field, which is basically a customer list.  I asked originally if this could be narrowed down and was told maybe they could clean up 5000 records which wasn't going to make much of a difference.

Comment: If this would have had problems from the beginning I probably would have looked for another solution, but after spending some time optimizing the code it worked adequately (1 or 2 seconds to populate and empty) up until we updated IE11 from 11.0.20 to 11.0.25.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a memory leak related to the built-in spellchecker in IE.  Instructions from Microsoft were to install Hotfix (MS15-106) which did correct this issue for me.